# Google Maps V3 Trigger Event Outside of Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, dom-events

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong in this code. My goal is to be able to click or mouse over a '< p >' element and have a corresponding marker to show its info window as if I had clicked on the window itself.

This is my code:

```
<style type="text/css" >

  html { height: 100% }

  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }

</style>



<script type="text/javascript"

    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">

</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) 
{
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
}



//Different icons if coupon or no coupon
var customIcons = {
      yes: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      no: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      }
    };


// Download XML from AJAX
function downloadUrl(url, callback) 
{
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
    new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
    new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if (request.readyState == 4) 
        {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
            }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
}


//AJAX: Send all locations within bounds of map
function get_locations(neLat, neLng, swLat, swLng, map, infoWindow)
{
    downloadUrl("Scripts/googlemap_ajax.php?neLat="+neLat+"&neLng="+neLng+"&swLat="+swLat+"&swLng="+swLng,      function(data) 
    {
        var side_html= '';
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) 
        {
                var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
                var tags = markers[i].getAttribute("tags");
                var coupon = markers[i].getAttribute("coupon");
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("latitude")),
                        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("longitude")));
                var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + tags;      
                var icon = customIcons[coupon] || {};
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
            {
                map: map,
                position: point,
                icon: icon.icon,
                shadow: icon.shadow
            });

            //TEST Side bar
            side_html += '<p onMouseOver="click_sidebar()">' + name + '</p>';


            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }

        document.getElementById("locationSelect").innerHTML = side_html;
    });
}



function click_sidebar() 
{
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[1], 'click');
    //alert("SOMETHING");
}


function doNothing() 
{
}


function initialize() //Initialize the map

{   
    var last_ne_lat;

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat; ?>,<?php echo $long; ?>);

    var myOptions = {

        zoom: 16,

        center: latlng,
        streetViewControl: false,

        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

    };

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var image = '/View/Images/map_icon.png';

    var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({

        position: latlng,

        map: map,

        icon: image,

        title:"YOU ARE HERE"

    });

    // Add listener to map
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
        var bounds = this.getBounds();
        var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
        var neLat = bounds.getNorthEast().lat();
        var neLng = bounds.getNorthEast().lng();
                var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
        var swLat = bounds.getSouthWest().lat();
        var swLng = bounds.getSouthWest().lng();
        if( neLat != last_ne_lat)
        {
            get_locations(neLat, neLng, swLat, swLng, map, infoWindow);
            last_ne_lat = neLat;
        }
    });

}


</script>


<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="locationSelect" style="width:100%"></div>

    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:70%; height:90%"></div>

</body>
```

In the 'get_locations' function I output some html where I call a function via mouseover.  This function is called correctly (The alert that is now commented out was working) however nothing is happening.
Does anyone see where I went wrong?

Comment: First I would advice you to use jQuery for Ajax calls. The implementations differ between browsers, and your code will not work in all of them. JQuery wraps that so you don't have to care.

Answer (score 1):

Your `click_sidebar` function has no access to the `markers` object that you defined in the `get_locations` function.

Do you use Firebug or some other debugger? Stepping through the code with a debugger will help you discovering these types of errors much more easily.

**EDIT:**
It would be good if you started using proper objects and adhere to a more object-oriented style. But, in the meantime to solve your imminent problem, move the declaration of `markers` to the global scope (below `customIcons` for instance)

Comment: I thought that could've been the problem, however, when I did move the 'google.maps.event.trigger(markers[1], 'click');' line to inside the function where markers was declared, nothing happened.
And no, I'd never heard of firebug before, seems useful.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you use firebug or some other debug tool. You will save so many hours of work! :-)